# updating to svn 1.9.4 via command line in mac

Tags: bash, macos, svn, command-line-interface

I am using SVN against my will. The current team I work with uses it for version control and they are not always available to help me. I am just trying to go from SVN Version 1.8.13 to the latest 1.9.4

I have download it and I have ran this command too

```
curl -o subversion-latest.tar.gz http://apache.mirrors.tds.net/subversion/subversion-1.9.4.tar.gz
tar -xvf subversion-latest.tar.gz
```

**I have combined these two different tutorials with no luck.**

[svn update version](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/10/updating-svn-mac-os-x/)

[stackover flow issue](https://superuser.com/questions/681405/how-to-install-svn-1-8-5-with-neon-on-mavericks)

I am STUCK at with the `configure` part..

```
mymac ~/Downloads/subversion-1.9.4/serf
$ ./configure
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
mymac ~/Downloads/subversion-1.9.4/serf
```

**UPDATE**

I exited out of serf path and on

```
`mymac ~/Downloads/subversion-1.9.4` file path i ran the `./configure` My command line ran a bunch of "checks" 
configure: Configuring Subversion 1.9.4 
configure: creating config.nice checking for gcc... 
gcc checking whether the C compiler works...
```

yes but eventually shot an error at the end...

```
configure: error: failed to recognize APR_INT64_T_FMT on this platform 
mymac ~/Downloads/subversion-1.9.4
```

- I have the latest version of XCode..

**UPDATE2 tried neon, again**

```
mymac ~/Downloads/subversion-1.9.4
$ sh get-deps.sh neon
Local directory 'serf' already exists; the downloaded copy won't be used
Local directory 'apr' already exists; the downloaded copy won't be used
Local directory 'apr-util' already exists; the downloaded copy won't be used
get-deps.sh: line 151: get_neon: command not found
Usage: get-deps.sh
Usage: get-deps.sh [ apr | serf | zlib | sqlite | gmock ] ...
mymac ~/Downloads/subversion-1.9.4
$ cd neon
-bash: cd: neon: No such file or directory
```

**UPDATE 3**

ran this command first ..

```
mymac ~/Downloads/subversion-1.9.4
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-serf=/usr/local/serf
configure: Configuring Subversion 1.9.4
configure: creating config.nice
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
```

I guess I should install a new version of serf?

```
checking was serf enabled... no

An appropriate version of serf could not be found, so libsvn_ra_serf
will not be built.  If you want to build libsvn_ra_serf, please
install serf 1.3.4 or newer.

configure: error: Serf was explicitly enabled but an appropriate version was not found.
```

I have no clue where to go from here and how to get around it. I already figure out that neon is no longer supported and I am using `serf` Can someone offer a different way to go about this? Please? Thanks!

Comment: Are you running the `./configure` from the path in which you extracted the `tar`? doesn't look so

Comment: Hi Inian.. I am inside the `serf` directory or file? I am not even sure what `serf` is to be honest.. When I ran the `curl` to get the tar file I was inside my downloads directory.. I was under the impression that I am in the correct path..  I just double checked and I am now in the latest subversion directory ..

`mymac ~/Downloads/subversion-1.9.4/serf`
`$ ll`
`total 236`
`drwxr-xr-x 22 mymac staff   748 Oct 20  2014 test/`
`mymac ~/Downloads/subversion-1.9.4/serf`
`$ ./configure`
`-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory`

Comment: **UPDATE**

I exited out of serf path and on 
`mymac ~/Downloads/subversion-1.9.4` file path i ran the 
 
`./configure`

My command line ran a bunch of "checks"

`configure: Configuring Subversion 1.9.4`
`configure: creating config.nice`
`checking for gcc... gcc`
`checking whether the C compiler works... yes`

but eventually shot an error at the end... 

`configure: error: failed to recognize APR_INT64_T_FMT on this platform`
`mymac ~/Downloads/subversion-1.9.4`

Comment: Did you build neon before that? `sh get-deps.sh neon` Can you do this before `configure`

Comment: @Inian I did that before but I ran into some issues..   get this.... 

`get-deps.sh: line 151: get_neon: command not found`

BUT before all that I get this..

`$ sh get-deps.sh neon`

`Local directory 'serf' already exists; the downloaded copy won't be used`

`Local directory 'apr' already exists; the downloaded copy won't be used

`Local directory 'apr-util' already exists; the downloaded copy won't be used`

`get-deps.sh: line 151: get_neon: command not found`

`Usage: get-deps.sh`

`Usage: get-deps.sh [ apr | serf | zlib | sqlite | gmock ] ...`

```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider using Brew or MacPorts, if possible. Then this can be as simple as:

```
brew install svn
```

If you really must install from source,
it might not be as complicated as the steps you described so far.
Try these much simpler steps *exactly*:

```
cd /tmp
curl -o subversion-latest.tar.gz http://apache.mirrors.tds.net/subversion/subversion-1.9.4.tar.gz
tar -xvf subversion-latest.tar.gz
cd subversion-1.9.4
./configure --prefix=/tmp/local
make
make install
```

This will (hopefully) build Subversion and install it into `/tmp/local`. Test with this command:

```
/tmp/local/bin/svn --version
```

If the output looks good, then repeat from the start, but use a different value for `--prefix`, as appropriate in your environment.

(I tried, and this worked well for me, right now, btw.)

Maybe it's not so simple. In that case please update your question with the output where you get stuck.